# Am I doing right to generate random number for a openmp accelerated program?

Tags: c++, random

I need to build a binary tree, and when branching the tree from list of points, I need to randomly pick a branch point, and I want to use `openMP` to accelerate my program, below is how I am doing it. It seems that the random engine `gg` would be shared and accessed by all threads, will this make the number it generated less random or slow down my program due to data race? If so, how could I avoid that? should I declare the `std::mt19937_64 gg` inside the build function?

```
#include<random>
#include<omp.h>
std::mt19937_64 gg(std::random_device {}());
int main()
{
    omp_set_num_threads(128);
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp single nowait
        buildFromPoints(0, 0, 1000000);
    }
    return 0;
}
void buildFromPoints(int idx, int lower, int upper)
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distr(lower, upper - 1);
    int povotIdx = distr(gg);
    // do sth with the random pivotIdx
    if (problemSizeIsSmall)
    {
        buildFromPoints(subPara1, subPara2, subPara3);
        buildFromPoints(subPara4, subPara5, subPara6);
    }
    else
    {
        #pragma omp task
        {
            // sub-tree left
            buildFromPoints(subPara1, subPara2, subPara3);
        }
        #pragma omp task
        {
            // sub-tree right
            buildFromPoints(subPara4, subPara5, subPara6);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, [random engines are not thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813592/c11-thread-safety-of-random-number-generators) when used with distributions, since the distribution changes their state. One solution is to declare them using the new C++11 thread storage duration specifier [`thread_local`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration), like

```
thread_local std::mt19937_64 gg(std::random_device {}());
```

Be aware though that not all standard library implementations support `thread_local`: g++'s libstdc++ supports it, but clang libc++ does not. And I am pretty sure VS does not support it either.

If you cannot use `thread_local`, then I suggest defining your random number generator local to your function. If you still want to keep it global, then you have to protect it with a `mutex`, but I don't think it's worth the overhead and slow-down.

More details about `thread_local`: [What does the thread_local mean in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983875/what-does-the-thread-local-mean-in-c11)